# Patching Array Inside An Array Using Reactive Forms in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I'm trying to display the `details` FormArray inside the `rows` FormArray. I need help since I can't display the data of the `details` FormArray. I only know how to display the `rows` FormArray but the `details` FormArray is much difficult for me. Here's what i have tried below. 
PLEASE SEE THIS STACKBLITZ FILE THAT I'VE CREATED.

[CLICK THIS LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-z98ens?file=app/app.component.ts)

Thank you.

```
  patchValues() {
        let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
        this.orders.sales.deliveries.forEach(item => {
            rows.push(this.fb.group({
                delivery_number: item.delivery_number,
                id: item.sales_delivery_id,
                details: this.fb.array([this.patchDetails(item.details, item.details.length-1)])

            }));
        });
  }

  patchDetails(item_details, i) {
        let rows =  (<FormArray>this.myForm.controls['rows']).controls[i]['controls']['details'] as FormArray
        item_details.forEach(item => {
            rows.push(this.fb.group({
                sku: item.ingredient_name
            }));
        });
        console.log(rows)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
details: this.fb.array([this.patchDetails(item.details, item.details.length-1)])
```

You are calling `patchDetails` while creating the form array, but the method doesn't return anything, instead you can modify `patchDetails` to return a `FormArray`, something like this

```
    patchValues(): void {
        let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
        this.orders.sales.deliveries.forEach(item => {
            rows.push(this.fb.group({
                delivery_number: [item.delivery_number],
                id: [item.sales_delivery_id],
                details: this.patchDetails(item.details)
            }));
        });
    }


    patchDetails(item_details: any[]): FormArray {
        let detailsFormArray: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
        item_details.forEach(item => detailsFormArray.push(this.fb.group({
          sku: [item.ingredient_SKU],
          name: [item.ingredient_name]
        })));
        return detailsFormArray;
    }
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-formarray-patch)

Comment: Thank you. Can you also help me with the HTML file? Thanks

Comment: @Joseph Added [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-formarray-patch), check that for the template